# QGIS Time Manager having trouble parsing valid dates from SQLite?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am getting the message below from TimeManager in QGIS. The error message is confusing because the date is displays would seem to be a valid format (I'm using YYYY-MM-DD).  The table is in sqllite format.

Any suggestions where to look for the problem?  I have done a quick check of this large table, but I don't see any problems with the date field.

[image: TimeManager error dialog]

Here is snippet of the table:

[image: Table showing date format]

Here is a snippet of the Field types in the table.  The date field is a QString.

[image]

Comment: what is your data source and what does your input time data look like?

Comment: The data source is an sqllite table and the date field looks like 2001-12-03.

Comment: adding that to your question, and screen captures of your date data would help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue with datetime columns: https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/159

As a workaround, you could cast to text. Text fields from SpatiaLite work fine for me.

Comment: I added a snippet showing the field as type QString.  So isn't it already text?

Comment: Can you share the data? I cannot reproduce your issue with strings.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded a small subset of my dataset that demonstrates the problem to the github page.